# Calculate UICollectionView contentSize in tableView's heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a collectionView inside a UITableViewCell. The collectionView's content is dynamic, hence, its height is dynamic too and the tableView cell's height depends on the collectionView's height. The collectionView cells have different sizes. The collectionView's height is always set to fit its contentSize height.

My problem is that the tableView's function heigthForRowAtIndexPath, is called before the collectionView is created (in cellForRowAtIndexPath) so, to return the height that fits the collectionView, I need to calculate it manually (which doesn't seem like a good idea for a collectionView with cells of different sizes).

I tried to use autolayout in order to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension but it didn't work (maybe I did it in a wrong way).

What is the best aproach to make a UITableViewCell consider the height of its subview in heightForRowAtIndexPath? Can I know a collectionView's estimated size without creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self sizing, which is available in iOS 8. There are plenty of good tutorials online, like this one: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/.

The idea is that you can use auto layout and a few lines of code in `viewDidLoad` to render a table view cell that dynamically fits the content in it.

Some more tutorials:

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html
- https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. I tried before to solve my issue using this approach but I was not declaring the constraints properly. Self sizing cells is a nice tool!

Comment: Great, glad it worked out. Yes, self sizing is a great new feature. Makes the process a lot easier than dynamically calculating height.

Comment: I have a little issue and maybe you can help. It works nicely but not at start. The autoSizing cell doesn't react until I pull my tableView up or rotate the device (I do tableView.reloadData() in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation). Putting tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad is not working for me. I believe it's because of the way the collectionView loads its content. Some suggestions?

Comment: Can you show me the code you use to load the data? Is it a loop?

Comment: Data in the collectionView is loaded with cellForItemAtIndexPath in the traditional way. Just:

`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("HorizontalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
cell.addSubview(button)
return cell`

Comment: I think you have an explicit width set on your label. If you remove the explicit width, it should work. (You can do this in storyboard by to the constraints tab and deselecting explicit width).

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can also do `reloadData` in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Apple engineering has pointed out that explicit width has to be unchecked for this to work. `reloadData` in `viewDidAppear` is a fallback if this doesn't work for you for some reason.

Comment: Also, I'm curious, what was the constraint issue that fixed self sizing for you?

Comment: I meant viewDidAppear, sorry for that: reloadData() in viewDidAppear() doesn't work. I'm not using storyboard. I don't think I am using explicit width. For height i use `collectionViewVerticalLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: collectionView.contentSize.height)` and then I update the constant in didEndDisplayingCell: `collectionViewVerticalLayoutConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height`

Comment: The layout constraint I was missing is the one that attaches the bottom the contentView of my tableView cell to my collectionView subview.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`?

Comment: Where exactly do you mean to try `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`?

Comment: For example: `cell.someElement.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 0` (some other solutions are also available on SO for how to use this)

Comment: The collectionView doesn't have that property. I really believe that the problem is because in viewDidAppear (of the ViewController that contains the tableView), the collectionViews contained in the tableView cells haven't loaded their data yet. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I repeat: once I pull the tableView up or reload the tableView by rotating the display, everything is show as I want.

Comment: Yep, this is a common problem with self sizing that `reloadData` should solve. However, if that's not working, it means (you're right) that the data hasn't loaded yet. You can use Grand Central Dispatch to keep track of the process and the UI. It works by completing the task of loading data before updating the UI (specifically `reloadData`). There's more here: https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/

Comment: I've been trying to use NSNotificationCenter in order to call reloadData() method in some step of the UICollectionView data loading process. I am not sure where and how. Some ideas? Thank you very much for your time, Shaan! You are being very kind.

Comment: Background Threads like I talked about in my previous comment (Grand Central Dispatch) works especially well in situations involving loops. For example: your data loading structure has a for loop that populates each element of the array. That should go in the task section, and the reloadData() should go in the UI section. No problem!

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally solved it! In the task section I put the `collectionView.reloadData()` which is called in my tableView cell `configCell(...)` method. In the UI section I call tableView.reloadData() (`let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                (self.superview?.superview as UITableView).reloadData()
            }
        }`.